# Extracting all reads from bam file which match read IDs in another file

Tags: sam, samtools, reads

I have a long list of read IDs of interest to me in a file called read_names.txt. it is simply in the format:

```
m54197_180831_211346/4981510/ccs
m54197_180831_211346/6226723/ccs
m54197_180831_211346/6619607/ccs
...
```

etc where these are the actual read names from a fastq file. I am then trying to find those in a bam file for which the fastq has been mapped, and I can accomplish this like:

```
for ID in `cat read_names.txt`
do
samtools view inbam.bam | grep $ID >> read_locs.sam
done
```

However, this method is obscenely slow because it is rerunning samtools view for every ID iteration (several hours now for 600 read IDs), and I was hoping to do this for several `read_names.txt` files.

I tried sort of flipping the script a bit and running samtools view first but it only returned the first read ID present in the file and stopped:

```
samtools view inbam.bam | for ID in `cat read_names.txt`; do grep $ID >> read_locs.txt; done
```

Am I missing something or is this the only way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Just as a general rule _never_ do `for var in $(cat file)`. Also known as [bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: thanks terdon, I will keep this in mind and find the better ways to handle this in the future. I use this method quite often so that is great for me to know!

Comment: Yeah, most of us use it very often until it bites us! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is still slow but grep has a `-f` option to take in a file

`samtools view inbam.bam | grep -f read_names.txt > read_locs.txt`

Comment: This took 30 seconds as opposed to several hours, so I'd say the overhead was definitely in samtools view. I feel silly because of how simple this was. Thank you!

Comment: just as a warning this can take much longer if the read name file is big.

Comment: I appreciate the heads up! Comparatively, I do not think it will ever take longer than the method I was using so it is still a great answer. (This is serving as a caveat to your warning).

Answer (score 2):

`samtools` can do this natively too using `-N, --qname-file` CLI option:

```sh
samtools view -N read_names.txt in.bam > read_locs.sam
```

```sh
❯ samtools --version
samtools 1.16.1
Using htslib 1.16
```